# Conditional style formatting using a format rules object in Javascript / React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I want to do some conditional formatting by applying styles to an element based on a matching a set of conditions. In the below example, I want to apply the supplied background color (red) in if the value (let's say 110) of the element matches the conditions lt (less than 150) and gt (greater than 100) value supplied in the rule.

```
"format": [
        {
          "tag": "bgcolor",
          "value": "#ff0000",
          "rules": [
            {
              "name": "lt",
              "value": "150"
            },
            {
              "name": "gt",
              "value": "100"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

```
<td>90</td> - would not have red background (not >100)
<td>120</td> - would have red background (>100 and < 150)
<td>100</td> - would not have red background (not >100)
```

What would be a correct way to implement this with JS?

Note the condition values (100, 150) inthe rules array are for example, they can be different values.
There can also be just lt or gt to apply the background color if it is greater than or less than some value

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a class, then dynamically generate your tds

```
.valid-score { color: red }


function generateTd(formatValue) {
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerText = formatValue;
  if (formatValue > 100 && formatValue < 150) {
    td.classList.add("valid-score");
  }
  return td;
}

function generateTdList(container, formatValueArr) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  formatValueArr.forEach(formatValue => frag.append(generateTd(formatValue)));
  container.append(frag);
  frag = null;
}
```

UPDATE

```
const compareFuncMap = {
  lt: (value, formatValue) => value < formatValue,
  gt: (value, formatValue) => value > formatValue
};

function generateTd(value, rules) {
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.value = value;
  const valid = rules.some(({ name, value }) => compareFuncMap[name](value, value));
  if (valid) td.classList.add("valid-score");
  return td;
}

function generateTdList(container, valueArr) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  valueArr.forEach(value => frag.append(generateTd(value)));
  container.append(frag);
  frag = null;
}
```

can it help you?

Comment: Thanks for the example ....  the condition values (100, 150) inthe rules array are for example, they can be different values. There can also be just lt or gt to apply the background color if it is greater than or less than some value

Comment: @Smarajit you could add a dynamic rule to compare whether reaching to your point to add that specific style

Comment: @Smarajit wait a moment, `rules.some` isn't appropriate here, you can try `rules.every` to fix it. sorry

Comment: yep it needs to check all the rules. I made a sandbox based on your approach. Works great!
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-austin-d3nto?file=/src/index.js